# output subnet id to output.tf file

Tags: azure, terraform

how can i output subnet id to an output tf file .

my output file :

```
output "subnet_id" {
  value = module.virtualnetwork_module.azurerm_subnet.subneta.id
```

but when i ran terraform plan . error below

```
PS C:\terraform\modules2> terraform plan 

│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│
│   on virtualnetwork\outputs.tf line 2, in output "subnet_id":
│    2:   value = module.virtualnetwork_module.azurerm_subnet.subneta.id
│
│ No module call named "virtualnetwork_module" is declared in module.virtualnetwork_module.
```

Here are the state list and show from my tfstatefile . I see the id listed but when i add to my output and run terraform plan show the error above . Thanks in advance for your help

```
PS C:\terraform\modules2> terraform state list
module.virtualnetwork_module.azurerm_resource_group.rg
module.virtualnetwork_module.azurerm_subnet.subneta      
module.virtualnetwork_module.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet

PS C:\terraform\modules2> terraform state show module.virtualnetwork_module.azurerm_subnet.subneta
# module.virtualnetwork_module.azurerm_subnet.subneta:
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subneta" {
    address_prefixes                               = [
        "10.0.1.0/24",
    ]
    enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = false
    enforce_private_link_service_network_policies  = false
    id                                             = "/subscriptions/bxxx3-xxxx-XXXX2-xxxx-XXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/dev1-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/appvnet/subnets/subneta"
    name                                           = "subneta"
    private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled      = true
    private_link_service_network_policies_enabled  = true
    resource_group_name                            = "dev1-rg"
    virtual_network_name                           = "appvnet"

output "subnet_id" {
  value = module.virtualnetwork_module.azurerm_subnet.subneta.id
}
```

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question. It's unclear where the output is defined based on what is shown at the moment.

Comment: In addition to Marko's comment, it looks like you are trying to use a module called `virtualnetwork_module` but that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be (no need for module):

```
output "subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.subneta.id
}
```